# Linearly independent vectors and matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $\{v_{1},v_{2},\cdots,v_{n}\}$ is $n$ linearly independent vectors
in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, what would be necessary and sufficient condition of $A$ ($n\times n$ matrix) $A$ so that the vectors $Av_{1}$,
$Av_{2}$, $\cdots$, $Av_{n}$ are linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The vectors $Av_1, \ldots ,Av_n$ are linearly independent if, and only if, $\det \left([Av_1 | \ldots |Av_n]_{n\times n}\right)\neq 0$.

Now note that $[Av_1 | \ldots |Av_n]_{n\times n}=A[v_1|\ldots |v_n]_{n\times n}$.

Comment: why is ther vertical lines in the matrix, before and after the dots?

Comment: @Mark It's a notation which suggests that I'm 'writing the matrix by columns'. The $i^{\text{th}}$ column of the matrix $[Av_1 | \ldots |Av_n]_{n\times n}$ is $Av_i$. Is that clear now?

Comment: yes so you gave me a property of matrix with column vectors that are linearly independent. So I need to find the condition of A that makes the matrix product with nonzero determinant correct?

Comment: So, the matrix product $\left([Av_1 | \ldots |Av_n]_{n\times n}\right)$ has to be invertible here

Comment: @Mark Yes, but that's not what I'm hinting at. Think about the last line in my answer.

Comment: Ok final thought, since vector set $v_{i}$ is linearly independent, matrix formed by column vectors is invertible, so in order for the matrix product of $A$ and $v$ to have nonzero determinant, $A$ also has to be invertible which makes the determinant of $A$ nonzero.

Comment: Yes, I'd stop at $A$ having to be invertible, though.

Comment: would that be necessary and sufficient condition of A?

Comment: @Mark Try to prove each direction. The answer to that question is contained in my hint.